# How can I use a groovy script that will return the dob from this object as a date?

Tags: groovy

How can I use a groovy script that will return the `dob` from this object:`{"id":7,"patient_id":7, "dob":"06/13/1949"}` as a date?

Answer (score 3):

Here you go:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def input = '''{"id":7,"patient_id":7, "dob":"06/13/1949"}'''
def slurped = new JsonSlurper().parseText(input)
def dob = Date.parse('dd/MM/yyyy', slurped.dob)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def patientRecord = [
    id         : 7,
    patient_id : 7,
    dob        : '06/13/1949'
]
```

Retrieve the Value of the patientRecord Object like.

```
echo patientRecord.dob
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for something like this:

```
def patientRecord = [
    id         : 7,
    patient_id : 7,
    dob        : '06/13/1949'
]
println Date.parse("MM/dd/yyyy",patientRecord.dob)
```

This turns your `dob` into a `Date` object.

Or do you even need to parse the json object?